Is the cardinality of $\varnothing$ undefined?
It is intuitive that the cardinality of the empty set is $0$.
However we are asked to demonstrate this using given definitions/axioms in Tao Analysis I 4th ed ex 3.6.2.
My question arises as I think the given definitions are insufficient to cover the case of the empty set.
The following two definitions are given to us, in addition to the usual basic set theory axioms.

Def 3.6.1 (Equal cardinality) We say that two sets $X$ and $Y$ have equal cardinality iff there exists a bijection $f : X \to Y$ from $X$ to $Y$.
Def 3.6.5 Let $n$ be a natural number. A set $X$ is said to have cardinality $n$, iff it has equal cardinality with $\{i ∈ N : 1 ≤ i ≤ n\}$. We also say that $X$ has $n$ elements iff it has cardinality $n$.

My reasoning is as follows.
The empty set has no bijection with any other set, because it has no elements for a function to map to the codomain. Therefore the first Def 3.6.1 doesn't apply.
Therefore the cardinality of an empty set is not defined.
I would value your guidance on where I have gone wrong.

What's wrong with there being a unique set with cardinality $0$?

3.6.1 didn't say "other". Mathematical definitions almost never expect you to assume that word is implied. 3.6.5 is fine if $0$ counts as natural.

$\varnothing$ has cardinality $0$ because there is a(n obvious) bijection between $\varnothing$ and ${i\in\Bbb N\mid 1\le i\le0}$. (@J.G. Counting $0$ as a natural or not is irrelevant.)

When they say "given two sets $X$, $Y$" they usually don't mean to imply that ${X,Y}$ has cardinality $2$.

@AnneBauval it would be if we deleted the first sentence of 3.6.5.

@J.G. Oops my bad, apologies!

To add to @AnneBauval's comment: In the book, just above definition 3.6.5, it says "(This is true even when $n = 0$; the set ${i\in N : 1 \leq i \leq 0}$ is just the empty set.)"

... And Tao does count $0$ as a natural.

But there is no bijection from the empty set to any other set. No bijection means the definition of cardinality doesn't apply. Where did I go wrong?

The empty map is a bijection.

(When you play with the empty set, things can get weird. You can't trust your intuition - instead you have to go back and stare at the definitions and work out what they say/require in these unusual cases.)

@JonathanZ i've never come across the empty map. What is it? What does it map, and to what? Can we show it is surjective and injective?

It's the unique map that has the empty set as its domain. There are many different ways to define what a map is, but I'd bet that Tao gives a nice rigorous one, so you can go back and read that, and figure out what a map with with the empty set as its domain must look like. (Be prepared to use the term 'vacuous' frequently :-)

The empty map $\emptyset \to \emptyset$ is a bijection (the type is important). More generally, the identity function on any set is a bijection. When $n = 0$ you have ${ i \in \mathbb{N} : 1 \leq i \leq n } = \emptyset$.

@NaïmFavier - Ooh, good point! I was wrong when I said it was unique - the range/co-domain matters.

For finite sets , the cardinal is simply the number of elements , in the case of the empty set therefore $0$.

I see that you got what you wanted & accepted one answer , @Penelope , I wanted to let you know that I have updated my answer with the last Point 4 to go into the "Intuition" behind the Bijection involving Null Set , since that was the Core Concern here !

First, I'll address 3.6.1. Setting $X=\varnothing$, it says that the empty set has the same cardinality as $Y$ if there exists a bijection $\varnothing \rightarrow Y$.
Now, your concern is that the empty set is not in bijection with any other set. This is true, but the empty set is in bijection with itself. Therefore, it is valid to say that $\varnothing$ and $\varnothing$ have equal cardinality.
(Aside: Note that even if the condition were always false, the definition would still "apply" to the empty set, in the sense that you could state facts about whether it and other sets had equal cardinality. It's just that those assertions would always be false.)
Now, I'll address 3.6.5. If we set $n=0$ in the definition, it says that $X$ has cardinality $0$ if it has equal cardinality with the set $\{i \in \Bbb{N} : 1 \leq i \leq 0\}$. Well, what is this latter set? Since there is no $i$ such that $1\leq i \leq 0$, we must have $\{i \in \Bbb{N} : 1 \leq i \leq 0\} = \varnothing$.
Therefore, $X$ has cardinality $0$ if it has equal cardinality with $\varnothing$. Since the empty set has equal cardinality with itself (according to 3.6.1, as we discussed above), this statement is true of the empty set. So, the empty set has cardinality $0$.
EDIT: I just read the comments more carefully and noticed that you're not familiar with the bijection $\varnothing \rightarrow \varnothing$, so I'll go over that.
Recall that, formally, a function $A \rightarrow B$ is a subset $R \subseteq A \times B$ such that, for any $a \in A$, there exists a unique $b \in B$ such that $(a,b) \in R$. Well, if $A$ and $B$ are both the empty set, a function would be a subset of $\varnothing \times \varnothing$ for which this condition holds. Note that $\varnothing$ itself is a subset of this cross product, and it satisfies the condition vacuously: we have to check that it holds "for all $a$ in the domain...", but there are no such $a$ in the domain, so the statement is considered true.
Therefore, $\varnothing$ is a function from $\varnothing$ to $\varnothing$, which we call the empty map. You can also check that it is injective and surjective, because these conditions are vacuously true (just like the function condition). So, it is a bijection from the empty set to itself.

Thank you @sambo - the gap in my understanding was precisely the bijection $\emptyset \to \emptyset$ and you've explained it. Interestingly, the precise definition of a function and bijection would mean there is no bijection $\emptyset \to A$ nor $A \to \emptyset$ where $A$ is non-empty. Am I right?

@Penelope That is correct: the empty set is only in bijection with itself - in other words, it's the only set of cardinality zero. In still other words, it's the only set with zero elements, which is perhaps a more intuitive way to phrase it: it's basically the definition.

@Penelope You might also find it interesting to note that, for any set $A$, there is a unique map $\varnothing \rightarrow A$ (we still call it the empty map, because it's still $\varnothing$). (In category theory language, we say $\varnothing$ is the initial object in the category of sets.) Moreover, if $A$ is non-empty, then there is no function $A \rightarrow \varnothing$ at all, because there's nowhere for the elements to go.

interesting! can i check I understood your recent comment. For $\emptyset \to A$, you said there is a unique map. I understand this to mean that there is a map which takes nothing (from the emptyset) and gives us all the elements of $A$. But this can't be a function because functions only map to a single element. Is this correct? That is, a map is not the same a a well-behaved function.

I'm using "map" and "function" interchangeably (as opposed to "relation"). You do have a function $\varnothing \rightarrow A$. Here's one way to think about it: to define a function $f$, you need to specify the image $f(a)$ of each element $a$ of the domain. If your domain is the empty set, there are no elements is the domain, so you don't need to specify anything.

The initial ordinal, $0$, is the set of all of its predecessors. Since $0$ has no predecessors, the initial ordinal is $\varnothing$. The empty map from $\varnothing$ to $\varnothing$ is the function you are looking for.

Ordinals are off topic here.

OP Doubt is valid , though easily resolved.
(1) Why Current Definition is enough :
$3.6.1$ talks about two sets having the Same Cardinality , without assigning a Natural number to that Cardinality.
Hence $X=Y=\phi$ will have the same Cardinality , which is as yet unknown.
OP is right that there is no Bijection between $\phi$ & every other set , hence $X=\phi$ & $Y \ne \phi$ will not have the Same Cardinality.
We can still claim that $X=\phi$ & $Y=\phi$ have the Same Cardinality.
[[ We have one trivial vacuous Bijection involving $\phi$ , Elaborate Discussion about this at the end ]]
$3.6.5$ assigns Cardinality $n$ when we have $1 \le i \le n$
Eg , we assign $n=1$ to $\{A\}$ & we assign $n=4$ to $\{A,B,C,D\}$
When we have $n=0$ , then $1 \le i \le n$ indicates $1 \le i \le 0$ , which is $1 \le 0$ , which is obviously the empty list. Hence $X=\phi$ works here.
Tao could have been a bit more explicit about this Case , though there is no major concern here.
(2) When we "Demand" that Current Definition is not enough :
Alternatively , let us say the Definitions are really not enough.
It is easy to add $3.6.0$ which "hardcodes" the Empty Set with Cardinality $0$.
(3) Why Current Definition is useful :
We want to make theorems about $\#(A \cup B)$ & $\#(A \cap B)$ (& more !) with $\#A$ & $\#B$ : Then those theorems should work even when $\phi$ occurs.
Hence we can not go with OP claim/thinking that "Cardinality of Empty Set is not defined" : All calculations should involve Natural numbers , with no Exceptions , within the finite Context.
Assigning $0$ to Empty Set makes us add & subtract $0$ where necessary.
Considering it undefined will make things more complicated later.
(4) What is the trivial vacuous Bijection involving $\phi$ :
There is no Bijection between $X=\{A,B,C\}$ & $Y=\{1,2,3,4\}$ , because we will consume all elements of $X$ while $Y$ will have 1 element left over.
There is no Bijection between $X=\{A,B,C,D\}$ & $Y=\{1,2,3\}$ , because $X$ will have 1 element with no matching element in $Y$.
When we have $X=\{A,B,C,D\}$ & $Y=\{1,2,3,4\}$ , then we can map $A$ to either of the 4 elements.
Then we can map $B$ to either of the 3 elements.
Then we can map $C$ to either of the 2 elements.
$D$ will map to the last element.
Hence we have $4!$ Bijections.
In general we have $n!$ Bijections.
Here is one way we can get the Bijection & reduce the number of elements in $X$ & $Y$ , until we get the Null Set :
$\#X=\#Y=4$ : $\{(A,3),(C,1),(B,2),(D,4)\}$ : $4!=24$ Possible Bijections
$\#X=\#Y=3$ : $\{(A,3),(C,1),(B,2)\}$ : $3!=6$ Possible Bijections
$\#X=\#Y=2$ : $\{(A,1),(B,2)\}$ : $2!=2$ Possible Bijections
$\#X=\#Y=1$ : $\{(A,1)\}$ : $1!=1$ Possible Bijection
$\#X=\#Y=0$ : $\{\}$ : $0!=1$ Possible Bijection
We can see that Empty Set has Exactly 1 trivial vacuous Bijection.
We have used all elements of $X$ , while no element of $Y$ is left over !
Hence $\phi$ has a Proper Bijection !

Here is a possible resolution:
Let A be a set with cardinality $n$.
$A\cup \emptyset=A$
$A\cap\emptyset=\emptyset$
According to theorem:
$|A\cup B|=|A|+|B|-|A\cap B|$
$|A\cup B|=|A|+|B|$
when $A\cap B=\emptyset$
(For exercise try to prove it).
Hence:
$|A\cup \emptyset|=|A|+|\emptyset|=|A|$
What do you deduce from that?
